# Page wrap hide element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide html element with id (#prev-project) only when in my page wrap is opened project-family1.html is selected.

And when in my page wrap is opened project-adaptation1.html then i want to hide element with id (#next-project).

Does anyone have any idea how to do that.TY.

Here is jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/duxzzzz/L0we7s40/

```
<div id="portfolio-wrap">
        <div id="portfolio-page">
            <div id="portfolio-content">
                <div class="container ajaxContainer">
                    <div id="protfolio-control">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                                <a href="#" id="prev-project" title="Previous Project"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
                                <!--Prev project-->
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center">
                                <a href="#" id="close-project" title="Close Project"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                                <!--Close project-->
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-right">
                                <a href="#" id="next-project" title="Next Project"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
                                <!--Next project-->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End #protfolio-control -->
                    <!-- Ajax will load into here -->
                    <div id="portfolio-ajax">
                    </div>
                    <!-- End #portfolio-ajax -->
                    <!-- End Ajax -->
                </div>
                <!-- End .container -->
            </div>
            <!-- End #portfolio-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- End #portfolio-page -->
    </div>
    <!-- End #portfolio-wrap -->
```

Comment: Please scale your code down to the minimal needed to represent your issue

Comment: This is the minimal...i don't know where is the problem so i put the block of code where it might be.

Comment: Your demo has a mountain of code non related to problem

Comment: Is it now better. https://jsfiddle.net/duxzzzz/L0we7s40/2/